# How to draw line in list adapter?

Tags: android, graphics2d, listadapter

I need to draw lines inside custom listView items and change its angle depend on the time. But how do I draw the line?

I tried to use a matrix and instead of drawing the line rotating the image of a line, but it didn't work.

```
public static android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options getSize(Context c, int resId) {
    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options o = new android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), resId, o);
    return o;
}

BitmapFactory.Options o = getSize(context, R.drawable.hand);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postRotate(30, o.outWidth / 2, o.outHeight);
handM.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
handM.setImageMatrix(m);
```